# How effective is the website Kudos in terms of spreading the word about one's research?

Tags: social-media

The website [Kudos](http://www.growkudos.com) offers a service whereby researchers can set up a profile, choose their publications from a database and add a short summary of their content (not the original abstract). How effective is

- setting up a profile with Kudos
- adding summaries to one's publications

in terms of making one's research better known? Is there any evidence to suggest that it's worth the time?

Comment: You'd be better off making your own webpage.

Comment: I have never heard of this and I have also never been led to a Kudos profile when online searching for information on people giving talks or authors of papers I found interesting. Usually, their lab websites come up first, then Twitter and/or LinkedIn and Researchgate, depending on their activity on those platforms. That's it for any type of "online profiles".

Comment: I also never heard of this website. After talking a short look, I do not want to use it either.

Comment: To the close voters: Could you please explain? Kudos is a website for researchers and ostensibly helps them spread the word about their research. How is this not in scope for Academia SE?

Comment: The explanation is already provided in the "put on hold" message. We do not accept shopping questions. You are seeking assessments of a web site. This is a typical shopping question.